# R won't train my data set

Tags: r, debugging

I at moment trying to train my data, but can't seem to get R to work as I want it.

The data consist of hand written digits (400) where for each hand written number is 18x18 pixels extracted.  So in total 400 x 324  data points as training data.

```
> class(train_data)
[1] "data.frame"
> str(train_data)
'data.frame':   400 obs. of  324 variables:
```

The code used for training is this

```
control = trainControl(method="cv",
                       number = 1,
                       repeats=0,
                       p = 0.9,
                       preProcOptions = list(thresh = 0.8), 
                       )

knnFit = train(x=train_data, 
               y=factor(testClass[1:400]), 
               method ='knn',
               trControl = control,
               preProcess = c('PCA')
               )
```

The problem here is that when i perform the train, i get an error message which i am not able to decipher what the problem is?

the error message is

```
Error in train.default(x = train_data, y = factor(testClass[1:400]), method = "knn",  : 
  Stopping
In addition: Advarselsbesked:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just judging from the error, one would assume that there are `NA`s in the training set.

If you run `sum(is.na(train_data))`, you should be able to see whether there are missing values in your set. If there are, then you could use the same command column-by-column to figure out where they're coming from.

Comment: Well...  the output from this is 

0.. so no NA

Comment: How should data be stored such that the train function would work?

Comment: I just had another, close look at the code, and my instinct is that you need to have parameter `number > 1` in your `trainControl()` call. Hard to do k-folds CV with only one fold.